# How to turn off upgrade message in Umbraco backoffice

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

Is it possible to turn off the Umbraco upgrade message in the Umbraco backoffice.  Don't necessarily want my users to see this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There is an `umbracoVersionCheckPeriod` key in `appSettings` section of the `web.config` that has the default value of 7. Set this to 0 to prevent "a new version is available" balloon.

```
<add key="umbracoVersionCheckPeriod" value="0" />
```

http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/webconfig

EDIT:

For umbraco version 7 this key might not be present in the web.config by default but you can add it manually and the notification will disappear.

http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Using-Umbraco/Config-files/webconfig7

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to exist in v7 for me... Adding it in seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

for umbraco 8 add
add this key in appsettings section in the web.config

```
<add key="Umbraco.Core.VersionCheckPeriod" value="0" />
```

https://our.umbraco.com/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/98912-how-to-disable-update-notification-backoffice

Answer (score 0):

### Umbraco 9 and Umbraco 10

Add `VersionCheckPeriod` to the `appsettings.json`.

```json
{
  "Umbraco": {
    "CMS": {
      "Global": {
        "VersionCheckPeriod": 0
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> When this value is set above 0, the backoffice will check for a new version of Umbraco every 'x' number of days where 'x' is the value defined for this setting. Set this value to 0 to never check for a new version.

References:

- https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Reference/Configuration/GlobalSettings/index-v9
- https://our.umbraco.com/Documentation/Reference/Configuration-for-Umbraco-7-and-8/webconfig/

The code for the API controller is also here: https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/e626fca2432582f052cb13654eedd9e60ef8723f/src/Umbraco.Web.BackOffice/Controllers/UpdateCheckController.cs#L47